# What are these spaceship silhouettes?

Tags: spaceship, object-identification

[image]

I know a few of them but I don't recognize them all.

Comment: I’m curious: what’s the source of this image? I couldn’t find another copy through Google Images.

Comment: @alexwlchan https://viralstyle.com/toistore/spaceshiptimeline#pid=5&cid=3162903&sid=front

Comment: The image has an error regarding the Star Wars lore. It's a long time ago, not a long, long, time ago. The galaxy is far, far away, but it's just one long time ago.

Comment: @ToddWilcox that's exactly what I said when I saw it. </nerd rage>

Comment: Are two TARDIS's called a TARDII?

Comment: @ToddWilcox: Ah but it's +30 years now!

Comment: @ToddWilcox: Yeah, and given the year, the nacelles on *The Enterprise* are wrong. Nerdolific!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In brief, from top-to-bottom:

- The Doctor's TARDIS (Doctor Who)
- Millennium Falcon (Star Wars)
- Battlestar Galactica (Battlestar Galactica)
- Saturn V rocket (Apollo missions)
- Discovery One (2001: A Space Odyssey)
- USS Enterprise (Star Trek)
- Serenity (Firefly)

And once again, with pictures and a bit more commentary:

- **The Doctor's TARDIS.** This is the time machine used in *Doctor Who*, and as far as I know the only one of these ships with any time travel capabilities – hence it appearing at both ends of the spectrum. A fault in its chameleon circuit means that it’s (almost) always disguised as a 1963 police telephone box.

  [image]
- **The Millennium Falcon.** This is the spaceship flown by Han Solo in *Star Wars* – so far it’s appeared in *Episode IV* to *Episode VII*. The “long, long time ago” refers to the [opening crawl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_opening_crawl) of the films.

  [image]
- **Battlestar Galactica.** From the show of the same name. This was the only one I wasn’t sure about, but googling the 148,000 BC pointed me in the direction of this show. Hard to see the profile, but here’s a picture:

  [image]
- **A *Saturn V* rocket.** This was used for (some of) the Apollo moon missions. Its first test flight was [Apollo 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_4), which took place in November 1967. Here’s a picture from [NASA’s website](http://www.hq.nasa.gov/office/pao/History/SP-4205/images/c233b.jpg):

  [image]
- **Discovery One.** This is the spaceship in *2001: A Space Odyssey*.

  [image]
- **USS Enterprise.** This is from *Star Trek*, but there’s some disagreement as to exactly which model the image depicts – see the comments below.

  [image]
- **The Serenity.** This comes from the *Firefly* series.

  [image]

Comment: It's the Enterprise NCC1701-A, the nacelles are different from the original that you have the image for.

Comment: It's not necessarily the Enterprise-A, the original Enterprise was refitted with similar nacelles and deflector dish. Plus the A didn't get launched until 2286.

Comment: Re @JAB's comment, since the year on the image is 2265 but (as JAB correctly points out) the -A wasn't launched until 2286, either the outline of the ship is wrong (probably) and it's meant to be the *USS Enterprise* with its original rounder nacelles, or...actually I'm not sure what the "or" would be, I just can't make that date work with those nacelles.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Star Trek's Prequel movies (i.e. the one that starts out with Kirk in Indiana stealing his Dad's car), but is it possible that it's the Enterprise from Star Trek XI?  If I remember correctly, it looks a lot more sophisticated and fancier than our classic Enterprise.

Comment: @Daniel Do you mean the JJ Abrams reboot? No, the nacelles on the new one are much more rounded and tapered.

Comment: @alexwlchan Yes I mean the reboot, and thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The simplest explanation for the date/nacelle discrepancy is the artist was drunk.  2265 marks the beginning of Kirk's 5 year mission.  It would have to be the original.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: NCC-1701 was refit for The Motion Picture. NCC-1701-A was its identical-looking [replacement](http://media.theiapolis.com/d4/hMF/i238P/k4/l241O/u1/w1H6/destruction-of-the-uss-enterprise-ncc-1701.jpg) (modulo the traditional "new-movie, new-bridge" antics) introduced at the end of ST4 and properly featured in two films. This could easily be the original ship.

Comment: @PreferenceBean: Regardless, given the timeframe, it's not the refit *or* the -A.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder. Er, right. I can't read. As you were :)

Comment: @PreferenceBean: LOL! The *Enterprise* was fairly prone to time travel, in TOS, TNG, the films... :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Indeed - didn't say he was right :D

Comment: Of note, the BSG is from the new show. The old show takes place in real time (late 1970s for the original, then early 80s for the sequel show). And the only place you'd know the date of the new show (c. 150 ka ago) is from a couple-second lead in to what I believe is literally the last scene in the show. If you glanced away or didn't see the episode, you'd have missed it. I didn't like the rest of the show much, but I thought the ending was one of the dumbest ever, so that particular number is unfortunately stuck in my head and I didn't even have to recognize the outline of the ship.

Comment: @MichaelS: Well, yeah, but remember: All of this has happened before, and all of it will happen again. So maybe the original show was a subsequent iteration. ;-)

Comment: The Millennium falcon appears in episodes III-VII (so far) - though its role in III is a very brief cameo

Comment: All this arguing about the Enterprise, and I'm just sitting here surprised to realize how much a Saturn rocket silhouette looks like a flying Empire State Building.

Comment: I'm so mixed on Firefly. I like the ship Serenity itself.......but I just couldn't catch on to the show.

Comment: As far as I know, the Saturn 5 was used for **all** Apollo missions to the moon.

Comment: @JRE you are correct - Saturn V was used for *all* of the Apollo missions _to the Moon_ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturn_V#Saturn_V_vehicles_and_launches).  There were other Apollo missions that didn't go to the Moon that used the Saturn I, but that's a different story.